# LZOP 1.03 ACC Conformance check fails

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel, buildroot

Trying to build LZOP as part of rpi-buildroot build.
Keep getting ACC conformance failure.

Is there a way to turn off this check ?
It seems like its justa different way of doing gzip. Is there a way to remove it from the build?

Comment: I have tried LZOP 1.04 but patches get applied to it from build root that fail. Is this package being maintained?

Comment: Ok I went into the configure script and removed some of bash code in it. That got it further. There were then some inappropriate ASSERTS in it. I am not a fan of ASSERTS especially ones that conflict with gcc for arm. Not impressed.

Comment: Hard to help without more details. Is this a host or target build? What errors do you get exactly? What is your .config? You mention rpi-buildroot, so presumably this is some kind of modified downstream repo? Do you see the same issue with upstream buildroot? We don't have any lzop failures in the autobuilders (http://autobuild.buildroot.net/?reason=lzop-%)